# R Hangs While Installing ChemmineR

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm working in RStudio with R version 3.5.1.

Originally I tried installing the ChemmineR package using the following line of code.

```
>BiocManager::install("ChemmineR")
```

This ended up hanging so I had to stop the process and close out of RStudio.

I tried again, and now it is consistently hanging after the following step.

```
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ChemmineR_3.32.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2593605 bytes (2.5 MB)
downloaded 2.5 MB
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest skipping BiocManager package and just use `biocLite()`:

```
> biocLite("ChemmineR")
> library('ChemmineR')
> packageVersion("ChemmineR")
[1] ‘2.30.2’
```

**EDIT**:
I re-read this question and realized you were on Windows and using a different version of R and a later version of ChemmineR. I re-tested this code and it still works:

```
R> biocLite("ChemmineR")
R> library("ChemmineR")
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ChemmineR_3.32.1     BiocInstaller_1.30.0
```